# Bootstrap datepicker not close automatically after picking a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use the latest Bootstrap datepicker.js. All works fine except that when I pick a date from the drop down, it does not automatically close it. I searched web and tried to use the following function in my javascript like the following:

```
 $('#selectDate').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    (ev.viewMode == 'days') ? $(this).datepicker('hide') : '';      
});
```

but when i use Google Chrome Dev tools, I realized that ev.viewmode was undefined. I am not sure how to move forward.

Comment: You should probably tell what plugin you're using? Is this it -> http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: I got it from GitHub yesterday :)

Answer (score 25):

I added  **autoclose: true,**     (with **semi comma** at the end and it works)

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    todayHighlight:'TRUE',
    autoclose: true,
})
```

Comment: I have seen several behavior when having this options, in which the last option has a comma at the end, I have always thought this is not necessary specially in the last option. Do you know why this happens? Should it always have a semi comma at the end? In which cases this doesn't apply?

Comment: use autoClose:true

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
$('#selectDate').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){                 
    $('#selectDate').datepicker('hide');
});
```

**Update:**

`autoclose` works fine when you use the updated version of datepicker present on github:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: github link was helpful

Comment: autoclose was what I was looking for, might update this with .datepicker({ autoclose: true });

Answer (score 12):

None of the above worked for me, however overriding the datepicker default option worked like a charm, and is a one-liner:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have multiple textboxes for which you have applied datepicker, then old solution might cause problem,
Please try this instead,

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
     $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Look out this, https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/500

> Note: Do not forget, we are using class selector of jquery, so you
>   need to apply datepicker class to your textbox.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$('#selectDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev)
{                 
     $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Simply open the bootstrap-datepicker.js
2. find : var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults 
   (Line 1391 in my case)
3. set autoclose: true

Save and refresh your project and this should do.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker( {
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
}).on('change', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it turned out to be a typo in the bootstrap-datepicker documentation.
Instead of "autoclose: true", it's "autoClose: true".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

//10000% work
Go to the bootstrap-datepicker.js file

Search for this:

```
'mousedown touchstart': $.proxy(function(e){
                    // Clicked outside the datepicker, hide it
                    if (!(
                        this.element.is(e.target) ||
                        this.element.find(e.target).length ||
                        this.picker.is(e.target) ||
                        this.picker.find(e.target).length
                    )) {
                        this.hide();  //remove this
                    }
                }, this)
            }]
        ];
    },
```

Comment: Are there any additional details you can share to make your answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the div with the class defaultdatepicker. The calendar control will appear. On Mouseleave it will dissapear.

```
 $(document).on("focus", ".defaultdatepicker", function () {

        $(this).datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
            autoClose: true,
        });

        $('#datepicker').css({ "opacity": "1" });
    });

    $('.defaultdatepicker').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('.datepicker').fadeOut(function () {
            $('.formattedStartDate').attr('class', 'formattedStartDate');

            $('#datepicker').css({ "opacity": "0" });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have in mind that answers containing only code are not considered complete.

Comment: When you hover over the div with the class defaultdatepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's work for me.

```
<input data-auto-close="true" type="text" class="datepicker-here"/>
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1830 it should be `data-date-autoclose` not `data-auto-close` and not as their *docs* says `data-date-auto-close` .. highly confusing.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
$(".date-picker").change(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".date-picker").datepicker('hide'); 
        $(".date-picker").blur();
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Please format properly and justify your answer. Check [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.